# T-SQL updates take longer than dropping and adding the column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to add a column such that *for all existing rows the value is 1, for all new rows the value defaults to 0*

Simple enough, I've created a script

```
ALTER TABLE Table ADD Column1 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
GO

UPDATE Table SET Column = 1
GO
```

The update query takes over 10 minutes on a 400K row dataset. **Where is the overhead here**?

I suspect I can add the column such that the default is 1 and then alter the default to 0 in less than 10 computational seconds (and may alter the script to do so for the next test phase).

Comment: Where is the damn overhead, how can this be optimized without the workaround I suggested.

Comment: which part takes 10 minutes? the first query or the second?

Comment: The update statement takes 10 minutes, the alter table is nearly instantaneous.

Comment: The column is added exactly as shown, therefor it is not indexed beyond any internal indexing performed by SQL Server.

Comment: @Oded Would indexing the column speedup the `update` query, is it something akin to `++i` vs `i++` where the value is updated inplace vs. read then updated?

Comment: @Sparksis - It might. To be honest, this is something that you would need to test and see.

Comment: Any update triggers on the table?

Comment: Have you repeated this test?  Was there other activity on the server?

Comment: Indexing the column would if anything slow down the update as you also have to update an index. It probably wouldn't be a noticeable change but it definitely won't help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `"Print"` and put two timestamps between the statements to checking which one has the over head. For solving an issue, you should first know the source that causes it. As my experience says, it's adding column that takes long to be completed.

Second, if you have about 400K records stored in the table, ofcourse adding a new column has a huge cost of IO. So if you let me know about your need, I will think of a better solution. Adding and removing columns, altering tables etc happen once in a blue moon and you shouldn't do such a things as an usual operation. It's simply not correct.

After all, I understand that you wanna add a column and update the values in less than 10 seconds, BUT it depends on many other things and your code (as it's so simple) is one of them. So I think you should think more about the idea than your code.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: I ran each query separately, it is was the `UPDATE` query that took 10 minutes, the `ALTER` query happened nearly instantly. :-/

Comment: @Sparksis what you want to do depends on many other parameters. The most important one is the performance of IO operations, simply the hard dist speed. I'd suggest you to use Profiler to see the costs, use Execution Plan and see what is actualy happening in your query and where is the cost. It will help you to make a decision.

Comment: I'd love to use the profiler but I don't have the appropriate permissions on the dev server.  -.- our DBA's insist that they have full control of these thing but are generally too busy to help with them when it is needed.

Comment: Ah, it's bad when you know something is wrong and you have no persmission to do something. BUT the good news is that you still have the Execution Plan icon in Management Studio, so use it. It'll give you some unbelievable information profiles will never can. Hope it helps. Also let me know if you had any question.